# Django turn list of objects into a table

Tags: python, html, django, loops

Given a list of objects in a Django view function, such as

```
[['1.1.1.1', A], ['2.2.2.2', B]]
```

How can I iterate through them in an html template to make table rows

```
Column1       Column2 

1.1.1.1       A
2.2.2.2       B
```

If you have a different way to do it, by creating the array/list in different way (no objects, but a list of elements for instance, please feel free to share).

Comment: What part are you struggling with? Its the same way as you would do it in python (nested loops), just with slightly different syntax

Comment: That slightly different syntax is my problem.

Comment: @Portu asking for links/references is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: [For loop](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#for).

Comment: @Ffisegydd I edited my comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your views:

```
context['table_info'] = [['1.1.1.1', 'A'], ['2.2.2.2', 'B']]
```

Then in your template use a [for loop](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#for):

```
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Column1</th>
      <th>Column2</th>
    </tr>
    {% for item in table_info %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ item.0 }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.1 }}</td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </table>
```

Comment: Interesting! I do appreciate it. Have a great day ahead.